# "Oves et boves" o "cani e porci"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-origin

***Oves et boves*** locuz. lat. (propr. «pecore e buoi»):

> - Espressione di origine non classica, con cui si vuole indicare, in tono tra scherz. e polemico, un aggruppamento eterogeneo di persone, per lo più prive di meriti e di qualità distintive (con senso analogo alla più pop. espressione ***cani e porci***): è un concorso poco serio, che metterà in cattedra oves et boves.

Treccani sembra lasciare intendere che l'attuale espressione "cani e porci" derivi dalla più antica "oves et boves".

C'è una ragione per la quale si è passati da un'espressione all'altra? Oppure esistevano entrambe ed è sopravvissuta solo la seconda?

Comment: Non mi pare che sia suggerita una derivazione, ma solo un'analogia.

Answer (score 5):

Anche secondo me, come suggerisce egreg, le due espressioni non derivano una dall'altra, ma sono semplicemente analoghe.

Non so cosa si intenda per "origine non classica", ma **Oves et boves** è una citazione biblica ([Giovanni 2-14](http://www.lachiesa.it/bibbia.php?ricerca=citazione&Cerca=Cerca&Versione_CEI2008=3&Versione_CEI74=1&Versione_TILC=2&VersettoOn=1&Citazione=Gv%202,13-25)), presa dall'episodio in cui, dopo aver visto i mercanti vendere appunto buoi, pecore e colombe, Gesù li caccia dal tempio.

Credo che la prima espressione sia semplicemente caduta in disuso, mentre la seconda, probabilmente di origine più popolare (visto la mancanza di fonti), si è maggiormente diffusa.

Comment: “Origine non classica” significa che non risale agli autori della classicità latina (bensì, a quel che pare, dalla Vulgata di s. Girolamo).

Comment: Si, ma "cani e porci" da dove viene? Feste popolari? Gare tra animali? I cani erano i guardiani dei porci in passato?

Comment: Io non ho trovato nessun riferimento, credo sia un modo di dire popolare.